# Log in with java and change url

Tags: java, php, android, html

I have a little problem: I need to get the source of a website in an android app, but to view the website I have to be logged in. I tried some ways, but it is not working. It is a little bit complicated, because it must work like this:
1. Log in on domain abcd.ef
2. Go to ghij.kl/internal
3. Go to ghij.kl/secure/data.php
3. Go to ghij.kl/secure/data/1.html and save source as string

I already tried to login via POST on abcd.ef, save cookies etc and use them on a new connection to ghij.kl, but that is not working, I receive error 403 from the website. I think the website checks the referrer, but I am not sure and I really need help of (or from?) some experts.

Sincerely, 
atom_dad